# Trill in Chopin Nocturne

Tags: piano, trills, chopin

Chopin's nocturnes have always been some of my favorite pieces of music to play. However, I was working through No. 17 when I came across this particular complex couple of bars. 
[image]

Particularly, the trill that is played over most of the notes in the picture. I'm really not sure how I'm supposed to play this. Do I continue to play the trill with my 4th and 5th fingers and leave only the remaining 3 fingers to play the rest of the notes in the right hand?

I've attempted this for a quite a while now, but even after having played piano for 14 years Im having trouble. I suspect that my 4th and 5th fingers are just too weak for this kind of fast action. I have no problem playing trills with my 1st, 2nd and 3rd fingers.

This is driving me nuts not being able to play this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Other editions make it clearer: trill each note, starting on the note rather than the auxiliary (where he specifies it with an accacciatura). You can see it in Scharwenka's edition [here](http://javanese.imslp.info/files/imglnks/usimg/6/68/IMSLP00468-Chopin_-_2_Nocturnes__Op_62.pdf).

Edit: I should clarify this a bit: Chopin is using accacciature in this passage to specify the starting notes of the trills.